# Name for bracket used for holding shift cables in place on down tube

Tags: road-bike, parts, vintage, shifting, terminology

I've got a '70s-era Motobécane<sup>†</sup> road bike which doesn't have any actual eyelets brazed on for guiding shift cables but instead has a strange chromed "bracket" which attaches onto the down tube with a screw and washer which has two small guides for keeping the shift cables in place (highlighted in green):

[image: Down tube with unknown "bracket" for guiding shift cables]

**What on Earth is this thing called?** — I've never seen something like this before.

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, it's a Moto*confort*, but I still haven't been able to discern any real differences between the two marques [despite trying my best to do so](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/41584/8685).

Comment: I would think it's just another version of a cable stop, they still make aftermarket ones for frames without braze-ons, that just looks to be an older outdated version, so i would call it a cable stop. But i am curious to see if there is an official name for this type.

Comment: I would call it a clamp-on cable stop, or a band-on cable stop.  This differentiates it from a braze-on cable stop which would require cutting to remove from the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several on line searches for "cable stops" have yielded numerous results so I guess the term is universal. They are available in single, double and triple cable models. Another variation is a "cable clamp", it function is to attach the cable housing to the frame. You will need to measure the frame tube diameter to get a clamp that will fit the frame.